# Is windows allows to set permission when folder or file in use? if yes is this fine?

Tags: java, windows, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

In Windows, I have to set permissions for folders, subfolders, and files while the service is running and the folder or file is in use. I have tried using icacls; it works, but my doubt is: is it okay to set permissions while the service is running and folders and files are in use? or will it cause any other issues?

Also, it took too much time to set permissions using ICACLs. Is there any other way to set permissions quickly in Java?

Answer (score -2):

It is generally not recommended to modify permissions on files or folders while they are in use, as it can cause issues with the running processes or services. It is recommended to stop the service and close any applications that are using the files or folders before modifying the permissions.

As for setting permissions in Java, you can use the Files class in Java 7 or higher to set file permissions using the setPosixFilePermissions() method. Here's an example:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetFilePermissions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\example\\file.txt");
        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw-rw-");
        try {
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, perms);
            System.out.println("File permissions set successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting file permissions: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This code sets the file permissions to read and write for all users. You can modify the perms variable to set the appropriate permissions for your use case.

Comment: `WindowsFileSystemProvider` doesn't support `PosixFilePermission` so this won't work on Windows. Calling `Files.getPosixFilePermissions(Path.of("C:\\"))` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: It is generally not recommended by whom?

Comment: @DuncG what is your opinion what you this about this  "Ss it okay to set permissions while the service is running and folders and files are in use? or will it cause any other issues?"

Comment: @user207421then you mean is this fine ?

Comment: @MohamedSafeek It really depends on each individual application - some may not be happy and might generate errors or crash, whereas others apps may be fine and work around any recognised permission edits. For example if you edit a Word doc and change the permissions to read-only the next Save attempt just becomes equivalent to having pressed Save-As, and it does not complain/report errors. So you need to judge based on what you run, and the implications on that app if the storage it previously did/did not have access to before now different